# QT - Set windows platform version

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++

I updated my Windows version to 10.0.15063.0 and every lib is missing, so I had to change the platform version to 10.0.14393.0 on Visual Studio, is there any equivalent for QT? The reason I ask is because QT seems to be using the 10.0.15063.0 version and so I get errors like kernel.lib / shell32.lib are missing, etc.

Comment: You mean in qmake? Because if you're using Qt with the Visual C++ toolchain, the steps will be exactly the same.

Comment: @McEricSir Sorry for my ignorence, but I just started using QT and Im not sure how to use qmake yet. On visual studio I just right clicked project properties and the Platform Version was an option under "General"

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

You need to install the Windows 10 SDK for 10.0.15063.0

If you have Visual Studio 2017 installed this can be done by using the "Visual Studio Installer". In "Individual components", check "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for Desktop C++ x86 and x64" and apply the changes.

### Option 2

#### Command line

If you build your project from the command line you can specify which Windows kit you want to use when calling `vcvarsall.bat`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64 10.0.14393.0
```

#### Qt Creator

If you use Qt Creator, the call to `vcvarsall.bat` is made automatically. You can see the call in Qt Creator settings in "Build & Run" > "Compilers".
However the GUI does not provide a mean to add extra arguments to the command line.

You might be able to force the arguments by editing `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\toolchains.xml`. This file should contains something like:

```
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.VarsBat">C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat</value>
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.VarsBatArg">x86</value>
```

You could change it to:

```
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.VarsBat">C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat</value>
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.VarsBatArg">x86 10.0.14393.0</value>
```

But keep in mind that you are not supposed to edit this file by hand and it may or may not work.

Comment: This answer provides a more modern solution that is supported and doesn't require manually editing configuration files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65997957/1329652