# How do I specify which Windows SDK version qmake shall target?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have Visual Studio 2017 Community edition installed on my PC.
Recently I installed Qt5.10.1.
I generated a VS project from one of the example .pro files:

```
qmake -tp vc cube.pro
```

However when I open this VS project and build it I get the error:

The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".

How do I specify once for all that qmake shall target Windows SDK 10.0 instead of 8.1 so that I don't have to retarget manually each time I generate a VS project with qmake?

Comment: A particular version of Qt targets a particular Windows SDK. `qmake` merely reflects that. Build a copy of Qt for the SDK you want, and its `qmake` will refer to it. `qmake` selects the exact build of Qt you need, with all its dependencies. I.e. to build for a particular Qt, you use its `qmake` when initializing the build folder.

Comment: I ran the qt-unified-windows-x86-3.0.2-online installer and selected MSVC 2017. Therefore I thought the qmake generated project should work out of the box. I also notice that the Qt command window says: Setting up environment for Qt usage...
Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup! This is although the 2017 vcvars.bat script is in my PATH variable. Seems like there is something wrong with the installer? Maybe 2017 is not supported after all? I notice that in the Qt/vcredist directory there is 2015 redists but not 2017.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot select Windows SDK version from `qmake`.
`qmake` expects that the environment is correctly setup before it is run.

If you use the command line directly, you will see the following message: `Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!`.
This means that you have to **run** `vcvarsall.bat` with the proper options to setup the MSVC toolchain including your selected Windows SDK version.

Some examples:

```
# MSVC 2017 for 64 bit 
vcvarsall.bat amd64
# MSVC 2017 for 64 bit using Windows 8.1 SDK
vcvarsall.bat amd64 8.1
# MSVC 2017 for 64 bit using Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.10240.0
vcvarsall.bat amd64 10.0.10240.0
# MSVC 2015 (installed with 2017 installer) for 64 bit using Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.10240.0
vcvarsall.bat amd64 10.0.10240.0 -vcvars_ver=14.0
```

And the help message from `vcvarsall.bat`:

```
Syntax:
    vcvarsall.bat [arch] [platform_type] [winsdk_version] [-vcvars_ver=vc_version]
where :
    [arch]: x86 | amd64 | x86_amd64 | x86_arm | x86_arm64 | amd64_x86 | amd64_arm | amd64_arm64
    [platform_type]: {empty} | store | uwp
    [winsdk_version] : full Windows 10 SDK number (e.g. 10.0.10240.0) or "8.1" to use the Windows 8.1 SDK.
    [vc_version] : {none} for default VS 2017 VC++ compiler toolset |
                   "14.0" for VC++ 2015 Compiler Toolset |
                   "14.1x" for the latest 14.1x.yyyyy toolset installed (e.g. "14.11") |
                   "14.1x.yyyyy" for a specific full version number (e.g. 14.11.25503)

The store parameter sets environment variables to support Universal Windows Platform application
development and is an alias for 'uwp'.

For example:
    vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
    vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64 10.0.10240.0
    vcvarsall.bat x86_arm uwp 10.0.10240.0
    vcvarsall.bat x86_arm onecore 10.0.10240.0 -vcvars_ver=14.0
    vcvarsall.bat x64 8.1
    vcvarsall.bat x64 store 8.1
```

If you use Qt Creator, you are out of luck. Qt Creator just detects the installed MSVC toolchains, but does not provide any means to add options to the `vcvarsall.bat` call or to manually add an MSVC toolchain.

Comment: OK so I ran: C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.10.1\opengl\cube>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 10.0.16299.0  Followed by qmake -tp vc cube.pro. However the resulting VS project still has 8.1 as Windows SDK Version.

Comment: Also I specified VS2017 x64 when I Installed Qt so why does not the Qt command window run this vcvarsall.bat file by default? It will become tedious when I have to do this each time I open the Qt cmd window.

Comment: @Andy It might be a bug that qmake ignores the selected SDK. For the vcvarsall.bat, it is not done by default because the Qt developers cannot know where you installed MSVC on your computer and which version you selected. You can go around the issue by writing a script that launches a command prompt and set both Qt and MSVC environments for you

Comment: @Andy If your goal is to develop Qt applications inside Visual Studio, you may want to use the Qt Visual Studio Tools: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

*Please read the answer of Benjamin T first. This answer elaborates on how it can be configured using `QtCreator`*

`QtCreator` allows to specify the arguments passed to `vcvarsall.bat`. Go to Tools > Options > Kits > Compilers:

- Clone the desired Auto-detected compiler(s)
- Fill in the desired Windows SDK version in the last field of *Initialization*:
  [image]
- Optional: update the Name to be able to find it back easily in the next step
- Under Kits > Kits, change the compiler(s) to your newly created ones (for the desired Kits).

Comment: This works indeed and is the correct procedure.