# Compiling libwebsocket with newest QT

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, compilation

It appears that libwebsocket is the only library that does not come with Qt, so I think I need to compile it and install it in my QT folder so I can use with other things.

I tried to compile libwebsocket and I got this error:

```
qwebsocket_p.h:65:10: fatal error: private/qobject_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include <private/qobject_p.h>
```

I believe this is because the QT in my system is old. I have a QT installation in my home folder. How should I pass it to websocket?

If it were with cmake I'd have an idea, but I've heard here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49108604/10116440 that you cannot pass qt folder to qmake. Is there a way to pass to make?

I also tried doing this in cmake:

```
find_package(Qt5WebSockets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Qml Quick Svg)
```

this way I can do `cmake -DQt5_DIR=/home/lz/Qt5.11.2 .` to set the Qt5 variable for everything except `Qt5WebSockets`, but the project fails to include `<QWebSocket>` anyway. If someone knows how to solve this, it'd also be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> private/qobject_p.h: No such file or directory

That means that the directory containing `qobject_p.h` was not added to the Include paths list. Make sure that your .pro has `QT += core-private` string.

> I have a QT installation in my home folder. How should I pass it to websocket?

It should be enough to put the file named `qt.conf`to the directory containing `qmake.exe`:

> qt.conf

```
[Paths]
Prefix = <qt root>
```

Comment: But it's an official QT project, it shouldn't have this error (missing qobject_p.h). Why do I have to tweak the project?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs All internal stuff (including plugins, addons, well, anything which depends on private/xxx_p.h) is only guaranteed to work with the single Qt release. If you've downloaded it for Qt 5.12 then it should compile with 5.12 only. Try to switch library's branch to match the version of your Qt.

Comment: That's what Im trying to do. I'm trying to compile this library using the QT installed in my home folder (5.12), while the one in my system is 5.3.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs So you should either (a) get 5.3 version of the library and compile it against your system Qt; or (b) get 5.12 version of the library and compile it against your Qt 5.12 in home folder using an appropriate qmake/qt.conf. Can you compile any random "hello world" app against 5.12? If not, why are you trying to build addons for it?

Comment: I think b) is better. I've put the file you said to in the path to qmake (not .exe, im on ubuntu) and qmake -v now gives me QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.1 in /home/lz/Qt5.11.2/lib

Comment: `lz@vm:~/v5.12.1 (1).tar.gz/qtwebsockets-5.12.1$ qmake
/home/lz/v5.12.1 (1).tar.gz/qtwebsockets-5.12.1/.qmake.conf:1: Cannot find feature qt_build_config`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Add `HostData=<path to parent of mkspecs dir from 5.12>` to qt.conf. Check `qmake -query` output. qt_build_config.prf must exist in <somepath>/mkspecs/features directory.